# MySQL group by url data rows that share root domain

Tags: sql, mysql

Currently have a database formatted as follows:

> id (unique id) 
>   url: http://domain.com/page.html

Urls are both from the same domain and from different domains.

This also needs to be accomplished in one query so that I can use things like limits when displaying the data to the end user.

**Data**

```
1, http://domain.com/about.html
2, http://domain.com/index.html
3, http://anotherdomain.com/index.html
4, http://anotherdomain.com/contact.html
```

**Expected Output**
*( I only want to return the first url (first being in which ever order the data is being sorted in, this example being "id ASC") of each group, where a groups is made up of urls that share a root domain.)*

```
1, http://domain.com/about.html
3, http://anotherdomain.com/index.html
```

Comment: Wouldn't a regular `order by` on the url field sort them into clusters?

Comment: Sorry, I added data, and expected output to better explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Why was domain.com/index.html excluded from the results?

Comment: @ Jonathan, I only want to return the first url of each group, where a groups is made up of urls that share a root domain.

Comment: So what are these ordered by? How do you determine the "first"?

Comment: in the expected output example, i'm assuming ordering by id asc.

Comment: What about when there are sub-directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work but may run into issues when joining tables

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(LOWER(table.url), '/',  3), 'www.', ''), 'http://', '') AS domain
FROM table
GROUP BY domain
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT T2.id, url FROM (
    SELECT MIN(id) AS id FROM Table1
    GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', 3)
) AS T1
JOIN Table1 AS T2
ON T1.id = T2.id
```

For your test data I get this:

```
1, 'http://domain.com/about.html'
3, 'http://anotherdomain.com/index.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't mean ORDER BY url, GROUP BY works on functions like substring() too.